# ReactJS getting started

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx

Trying t get the basic example of a component working. Following steps are what I followed as a combination of various getting started guides

Set up node dependencies as follows

```
 "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "~0.8.0",
    "forever": "0.14.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-chmod": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.8.0",
    "grunt-ssh-deploy": "~0.2.8",
    "react": "15.1.0"

  },
```

index.html looks like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
     <div id="outer-container">
    <h1>This is the outer container</h1>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/outerContainer.js"></script>
```

// The component js file

```
  var Hello = React.CreateClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div> 
        <h1> Hello at {this.props.now} </h1>
        </div>
    }

});


ReactDOM.render(<Hello now = { new Date().toString()} />, 
    document.getElementById('outer-container'));
```

It errors out with the following errors

```
react-dom.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' of undefined
```

and

```
 Uncaught TypeError: React.CreateClass is not a function
```

I am trying to use this on the clientside. And I see both source files loaded in the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though the guides you followed might be a bit out of date. Here's a couple things:

- `React.renderComponent` hasn't been current for quite a while. The current way to render a component to the DOM is to use `ReactDOM.render`:

  ```
  ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello now={new Date().toString()} />, 
      document.getElementById('outer-container')
  );
  ```
- You have a case-sensitivity issue: you're calling `react.CreateClass`, when the method is actually `React.createClass`. JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.
- You need to put your script tag *after* the div you want to render your component into. Since your script file executes inline, the call to `document.getElementById` will fail, as that element does not exist on the page yet.
- The script tag uses the type `text/jsx`, which browsers can't natively understand. You will need to include a browser-supported jsx processor. Babel's [browser.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js) should work, but you'll need to change the `type` from `text/jsx` to `text/babel`:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> P4 Web Query </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="outer-container">
        <h1>This is the outer container</h1>
      </div>
      <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/outerContainer.js">/script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks thats helpful, I edited my files based on yur response but still dont get it working. See the edited question

Comment: You need to include `react-dom.js` _after_ `react.js`. Order is important.

Comment: You're also still using the capitalized `CreateClass`. It needs to be lower-cased: `createClass`